# ViewController Delegate Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, delegates, viewcontroller

I am in need of some help please. I have been stuck on this issue all day and I cannot find a fix. I will try and be as clear as possible with my problem.

I have 2 ViewControllers. One is called ViewController and the other is called GameViewController. In the ViewController I have my home screen menu and on the GameViewController I have the Game screen AND the Game Over screen. When you press play from ViewController it takes you to the Game, and then when you die you stay in the same GameViewController but in a Game Over view. If you press restart in the Game Over screen a segue takes you back modally to the Game Screen.

So here is the problem I am having.

When you die for the first time and go to the Game Over screen, you can click on home and it will take you home, BUT if you press restart, then die again (that's twice ) and then try to press home from the Game Over Screen it will NOT run the code inside the home button. The button actually works, I have an NSLog in their and it shows in the debugger screen. Weird I know. Please see below code that will show everything I have done to try and make this work.

In GameViewController.h //Above all the #imports

```
@class GameViewController;

@protocol GameViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void) GameViewControllerDidCancel:(GameViewController *)controller;
- (IBAction)homeBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

And this just after the the close } in @Interface

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <GameViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

In GameViewController.m after the @Implementation

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

And this in my homeBtn

```
- (IBAction)homeBtn:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"home btn pressed");

   [self.delegate GameViewControllerDidCancel:self];

}
```

Then in my ViewController.h

```
#import "GameViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController : UIViewController <GameViewControllerDelegate>
```

ViewController.m

When I press play

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    GameViewController* controller= [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GML"];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
    [audioPlayer stop];
    }else {

        UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"
                                                      bundle:nil];
        GameViewController* controller= [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GML"];
        controller.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }

}
```

And the method that I try to call from my homeBtn is also in here

```
#pragma mark - GameViewControllerDelegate

- (void) GameViewControllerDidCancel:(GameViewController *)controller {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I am pretty sure that is it. So like I said before, the restart button is just linked to a segue to return back to the Game screen.

Please guys, I am really desperate now, I am completely out of ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check by adding NSLog to GameViewControllerDidCancel delegate method whether the method called or not?

Comment: Putting URGENT in the title won't help you get better/faster help.

Comment: I added an NSLog in the GameViewControllerDidCancel method in my Viewcontroller. The log appears if I dont restart in the gameOver screen. But if I restart and then die and press home the log does not appear. BUT the NSLog in the HomeBtn does appear. So the button is working but the method is not firing

Comment: jcm writing "Putting URGENT in the title won't help you get better/faster help" isn't going to help me either. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a convoluted view hierarchy and hard to understand.

What exactly does the `restartGameButton` do. Is it an unwind segue?

> When you press play from ViewController it takes you to the Game, and then when you die you stay in the same GameViewController but in a Game Over view. If you press restart in the Game Over screen a segue takes you back modally to the Game Screen.

What is the `GameOver view` thing? Once you say its a view in the `GameViewController`, but then again you say if you press restart a segue takes you back modally to the Game Screen (i.e. `GameViewController`) which implies the GameOver Screen is also a `ViewController`.

Why use modal presentation when it is a actually a navigation stack that you want?

**Best solution in my opinion:**

Make 3 ViewControllers, one for the Start, one for the Game, one for GameOver. Embed the ViewControllers in a navigation controller and push and pop with this one instead of presenting many modal views on top of one another.

Comment: Hi Mario, The GameViewController holds 2 Views. GameView and GameOverView. GameOverView is hidden. When you die GameOverView is un hidden. then when you press restart its hidden again. I have linked the restart button to the GameViewController so it can restart the game again. Is that the wrong way to do it?

Comment: What then is the code to restart the game, because above you say the restart button "takes you back modally to the Game Screen". which is something completely different that unhiding a view. See my edit an best solution. You will be best helped with a navigation controller. if you don't want the navigation bar, you can hide it in the navigationcontroller.

Comment: yeah what I mean by that is, in the storyboard, I control click the restart button and dragged it to my GameViewController and then selected Modal. There is no code in the button just that segue

Comment: that won't work. when you control click and select modal, it creates a segue. this segue will instantiate a NEW view controller every time and present it modally. that means the delegate will never be set. so in reality, like this, you don't actually HIDE the gameOverView, you create a NEW GameViewController with the gameOverView initially hidden. So make 3 Viewcontrollers out of it and do it like I said to make it work quickly. then read up on segues to understand the problem better.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I will try what you said. Im trying to learn mate, so thanks for being patient :). cheers